# How to change window buttons to theme buttons in unite-gnome extension

Tags: gnome, themes

My theme buttons look like:

[image: theme buttons].

I installed the unite extension and changed the theme color to auto, but it is only showing this red button:

[image: this red button]

How can I make it apply to my theme button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be automatic detection by looking at the code, but it does not work for me either.

I simply change the default Buttons like this:

Goto `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/unite@hardpixel.eu/themes/default` and replace the button graphics with the ones from your theme. Change is seen instantly without restarting gnome-shell or unite.

If you don't already find your themes buttons ready to copy in the unite@hardpixel.eu/themes folder, you most possibly find them under `~/.themes/[YOUR_THEME]/assets` or `/usr/share/themes/[YOUR_THEME]/assets`

May the source be with you.